# I read the error and can't figure out the solution. Why am I getting a "javafx.fxml.LoadException"?

Tags: java, javafx

When I run the following code in eclipse with java 18 I get an error. Please Help. The fxml is generated using the scene builder.
I read the error, but I don't understand the solution. In Main.fxml he thought everything was fine until line 9.

I used this video as a reference.
https://youtu.be/N3LZM4WFHBY?list=PLZPZq0r_RZOM-8vJA3NQFZB7JroDcMwev

Main.java:

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
package application;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Controller {
    
    public void up(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("UP");
    }   
    public void down(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("DOWN");
    }   
    public void right(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("RIGHT");
    }   
    public void left(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("LEFT");
    }
    
}
```

Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="286.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#up" text="UP" />
      <Button layoutX="536.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#right" text="RIGHT" />
      <Button layoutX="273.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#down" text="DOWN" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="188.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#left" text="LEFT" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/suyak/eclipse-workspace/Message/bin/application/Main.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:933)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3331)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
    at FirstJavaFX/application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Controller
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:931)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: here is the relevant part of your stacktrace: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Controller

Comment: A mentioned by @Stultuske this is because of class `Controller` not being found. This could be because the dependency is missing. FWIK, Controller is a JavaFX class so you might want to check if JavaFX lib is correctly added to the project.

Comment: your controller is in the package `application`. So you need to use `fx:controller="application.Controller"` to correctly reference it

Comment: @kaysush the Controller class is right there. OP is just not using the fully qualified name to reference it.

Comment: You can solve this either by using `fx:controller="application.Controller"` (the fully qualified name of your controller class) or, I believe, by adding an `<?import application.Controller?>` instruction to your FXML file. You also need to change your controller class to import `javafx.event.ActionEvent` instead of the AWT equivalent (that's not related to your current error, but will prevent a future error from occurring).

Comment: ///controller class to import `javafx.event.ActionEvent` your current error, but will prevent a future error from occurring). ///   I used it as a reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

[Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231897/i-read-the-error-and-cant-figure-out-the-solution-why-am-i-getting-a-javafx-f/73232479#comment129333666_73231897):

> You can solve this either by using `fx:controller="application.Controller"` (the fully qualified name of your controller class) or, I believe, by adding an `<?import application.Controller?>` instruction to your FXML file. You also need to change your controller class to import `javafx.event.ActionEvent` instead of the AWT equivalent (that's not related to your current error, but will prevent a future error from occurring).

Writing `fx:controller="application.Controller"` fixed it.